# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ \frac{n\log(n)}{e^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\ \dfrac{n\log(n)}{e^n}$ convergent or divergent?

How can I solve this question? Please Help.

Thank you.

Comment: but, how Liebnitz test is applicable here..? I can't ...Actually I cannot choose the series whose sequence of partial sum is bounded...from the give series.

Comment: you don't need the sequence of partial sums to apply Leibniz test.

Comment: oh...sorry I thought Dirichlet's test...but is the sequence ${n log(n)/e^n}$ is m.d and converging to zero..?

Comment: For that you need to see the derivative of $\frac{n\ln n}{e^n}$, if you know how derivative implies monotonicity. Then obviously calculating the limit you can conclude

Comment: thank you sir....I got it...@ Kushal Bhuyan

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series equals:

$$\frac{2 \log 2}{e^2} + \sum_{n\ge 3} \frac{(-1)^n n \log n}{e^n}$$

Check that on $[3, \infty)$, the function $x \mapsto \frac{x \log x}{e^x}$ is decreasing (by studying the derivative). Hence, by the alternating series test (check the other trivial conditions), the series converges.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, one may observe that
$$
e^n\ge n^4, \qquad n \ge 9,
$$ giving
$$
\frac{n\ln n}{e^n}\le \frac{n\ln n}{n^4} \le \frac1{n^2}, \qquad n \ge 9,
$$ and
$$
\left|\sum_{n\ge9}(-1)^n\frac{n\ln n}{e^n}\right| \le \sum_{n\ge9}\frac{n\ln n}{e^n} \le \sum_{n\ge9}\frac1{n^2}<\infty
$$ the initial series is *absolutely convergent* thus it is *convergent*.